# DISTINCT & UNIQUE SELECT statement in SQL

Tags: sql

I'm trying to retreive data from a table with the following code:

`SELECT DISTINCT  billing_city, invoice_id FROM invoice ORDER BY invoice_id`

However, the returned table includes duplicated cities, because each order from the same city has a different **invoice id**.

So, my question is: Can I somehow return 1 specific column with DISTINCT values, and keep the rest of the table UNIQUE?

Edit: The desired result is in the upper image - each city should only be included once in the returned table, but at the same time, I should also have returned the invoice_id column with it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Use aggregation, eg `max(invoice_id)`, depending on which logic you want to determine which row to keep, you have not stated...

Comment: `DISTINCT` applies to the entire row. Please include some sample data and the expected result to understand exactly what you need.

Comment: I included 2 screenshots: The desired result is on the upper one - each city should only be  returned once.

Comment: Screenshots are not working.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve a list of unique billing cities along with their corresponding invoice IDs, use a subquery to select distinct billing cities from the invoice table and join it back to the original table using the billing_city column and an inner join. Customize this query as per your needs.

```
SELECT invoice.billing_city, invoice.invoice_id 
FROM invoice 
INNER JOIN 
   (SELECT DISTINCT billing_city FROM invoice) AS cities 
   ON invoice.billing_city = cities.billing_city 
ORDER BY invoice.invoice_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select distinct biling_city then you need to chose one invoice_id per billing_city or need to concat all the invoice_id into a string

```
SELECT billing_city, min(invoice_id) FROM invoice 
group by billing_city
```

Above query will return distinct billing_city with minimum invoice_id per billing_city